# Can we user razorpay plugin with reactnative and expo

Tags: react-native, expo, razorpay

In plugin they mentioned that the razorpay is not going to work with expo. i want to acces razorpay plugin in my react native app. is there any way..? i am using expo. please help me

Answer (score 0):

if the react native library you want requires a linking step, then you can `detach` and use `ExpoKit` directly.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html

Answer (score 0):

[EAS](https://blog.expo.dev/eas-build-april-preview-update-ebd7dff9dd25) builds officially released in Expo SDK 42 makes it possible to run native modules on expo projects.

In order to make sure Razorpay wrapper works correctly:

- Create a dev build of your expo app by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/).
- run your project by running the following command
- For ios

  `expo run:ios`
- For android

  `expo run:android`